# Facebook Sharing PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP .. I'm working on a button to allow the user to share the current page on Facebook..
I've tried to search entirely on this forum and google..
I've encountered with `sharer.php` but that didn't worked as for apps developer for **facebook**, the share button was sticking out of the place..

Is there any other ways to share it on Facebook??

```
<?php

    ob_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit']));
    {
        header('Location: http://www.private.com/ProjectA/download.php?filename=index.html');   
    }
    if(isset($_POST['share']))
    {
        /* facebook sharing function*/
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you read this : [Developers.Facebook : Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)

Comment: Why? what's the error with sharer.php ? That's good option you dont need permissions for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.yoursite.com/sharepage.php" target="_blank">
 Share on Facebook
</a>
```